# Excel VBA For-Next Loop to extract data from one WB to another

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I am working on a for loop that extracts entire rows of data based on the string in the 12th column being equal to "Airfare."

The idea is to copy the rows of data where column 12 (EXPENSE_TYPE) is Airfare and paste it into a second workbook.

My code, below, is not properly looping through all 120 rows of data. When I run my macro, it only extracts the first row of data where my criteria is met. Let me know if you can find my issue. Thanks!

```
Sub exportDataToOtherWorkbook()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim p As Integer
Dim q As Integer
Dim erow As Long

lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastRow
    If Cells(i, 12) = "Airfare" Then
    Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 16)).Select
    Selection.Copy


Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\users\andrew.godish\Desktop\Practice Files\masterPracticeExtractDataWBtoWB.xlsx"

p = Worksheets.Count
    For q = 1 To p
        If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(q).Name = "Sheet2" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Select
        End If
    Next q

    erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

    ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You never initialized `lastRow` so it's `0`.

Comment: I apologize, I did not copy my code over in its entirety. It is now correct, the lastRow variable is now initialized. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, qualify your ranges/cells? Edit: when you hop between books/sheets, how does the computer know which `cells` you mean? For example, `If Cells(i, 12) = "Airfare" Then`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest an alternative to looping through each row. Loops are very inefficient and should be avoided if possible.

Assuming your data is stored on "Sheet1" (change to meet your requirements) of the workbook you are copying from, you can filter column 12 and copy all of the data in a more simple command like this:

```
Sub Test()

        'Declare source and destination variables
        Dim sourceWB As Workbook, destWB As Workbook

        Set sourceWB = ThisWorkbook

        'Open the workbook to copy the data TO
        Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\users\andrew.godish\Desktop\Practice Files\masterPracticeExtractDataWBtoWB.xlsx"
        Set destWB = ActiveWorkbook

        sourceWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:P1").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="Airfare"

        'The first offset on the copy is to avoid copying the headers each time, the second offset is to find the last row in the
        'list then offset to the next row. Copies data to new workbook
        sourceWB.Sheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).Copy Destination:=destWB.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

        destWB.Save

        'Clear the filter from the source worksheet
        If sourceWB.Sheets("Sheet1").AutoFilterMode Then sourceWB.Sheets("Sheet1").ShowAllData

End Sub
```

I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but I think this may be an easier, less error-prone method.

So this method follows these steps:

- Open the destination workbook
- Filter `Sheet1` on column 12 for "Airfare" (be sure to change `Sheet1` if necessary)
- Copy and paste the filtered range to the destination worksheet and workbook
- Remove the filter applied to column 12 in the source worksheet

The confusing part may be the use of `Offset(1)`. I use that on the copy to avoid copying the column headers (it offsets the copy area by one row down). I use it on the destination to avoid overwriting the last row (we must find the last used row, then increment down one row).

Comment: I like it! Only change I might add is `Set destWB=Workbooks.Open`

Comment: @findwindow That was my first try but for some reason I got a run-time error when I did it that way. I've no clue why, I probably made a silly error.

Comment: Huh. Odd. No big deal^_^;

Comment: @Soulfire - I like this method much better. Thanks for showing this to me.

Comment: No problem, it just so happened I was working on a project which required filtering and copying data so it was fresh in my mind! If you don't mind clicking the green check mark if this helped I'd appreciate it, it helps other users know that I (occasionally) know what I am talking about. Happy coding!

Comment: @Soulfire - I just posted another question that I think you can help me with; Q: "Excel VBA - In need of more efficient code, some kind of loop", in case you want to search for it. It is using the exact code you showed me yesterday. Take a look when you get the chance. Thanks man!